# Manejo de valores nulos en For Each

Tags: genexus

Buen día, ¿cómo es el manejo de los valores nulos en los For Each de genexus, específicamente en el Where? Ya intenté con la función isempty() pero no funcionó

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Podes probar con IsNull(). asi...

```
For each
Where IsNull(TuCampo)
   ...   ...
   ...   ...
EndFor
```

Agrego link a la documentación oficial: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2357,IsNull+function

Comment: Si me funcionó el isnull(), gracias